# Statute of limitations and constant damages

Tags: united-states, statute-of-limitations

Say someone builds a house improperly and damages accrue over the entire life of the house.

Is the statute of limitations meaningless in these cases because it is constantly reset by the damages? Or is only the first damage counted? If there are repeat violations doesn't that mean I could sue anytime?

Comment: Usually you would notice these damages and sue for the cost to bring it up to spec, where the damages do not continue to occur. Once you sue, you are supposed to use those proceeds to repair the house, if you don't, that's on you. So I'm confused, why wouldn't you sue when the first damage occurred and have it rectified?

Comment: Lack of resources to sue

Comment: It's your job as a homeowner to mitigate damages once you notice them... You can't say "well, it started out as a $5000 mistake, but because I couldn't afford to fix it, I'm suing you 20 years later for the full value of the property"...

Comment: But legally it shouldn't matter

Comment: *It does though*, you have a duty to mitigate damages, if you don't, the person is only liable up to the amount it would have cost to fix it when the damage was new. For example if you find a small leak in a pipe, but wait until one wall of your house is rotted out, black mold has set in, and the foundation is bad, the maximum damage you could be awarded would be the cost to repair the pipe and a little bit for superficial repair of the wall, they would not be liable for the entire house...

Comment: it matters **a lot** where this happens. building laws in California are different from New Jersey. Some codes might provide a *warranty* for things such as foundations for a certain time, others might not.

Answer (score 5):

### Limitations start to run when the prospective plaintiff first becomes or should have become aware of the cause of action

Let’s give a concrete example. Let’s say a foundation starts to sink causing a wall to crack. The limitation period starts to run from when a prudent owner should have become aware of the cracking.

Further, the builder is only liable for the foundation repair, initial cracking and the necessary costs the owner went to to prevent further damage. The owner has a legal duty to mitigate the loss; if they don’t then they are liable if, say, the wall collapses or the roof buckles.